# Не находит расширения в VS Code.Операционка-mac os

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos, proxy, xhr, visual-studio-extensions

Всем доброго утра/дня/вечера/ночи.Я только начал свой путь в программировании,прошу отнестись с пониманием. Вопрос такой:при попытке скачать расширения в Visual Studio Code выдает ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал повсюду ответ, никак не могу найти то, что нужно.
Заходил в Help->Toggle Developer Tools
Вот, что выдает в Console:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее всем благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет доступа к https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. Если не знаете почему - спросите у провайдера. Перед этим советую выключить прокси (если таковой имеется) и заглянуть в файл `/etc/hosts`.